# Tabulator select editor buggy in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, tabulator

I'm having an issue with tabbing out of a select editor in Tabulator using IE11. To rule out something in my code I checked the Tabulator website examples: [Editable Data example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5#editable)

When tabbing out of a select editor the rendered list remains displayed. In the image example I've already tabbed out of the Gender cell but the list does not disappear. This does not happen in Chrome, Firefox, or Edge.

Any thoughts on how to work around this?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Tabulator's compatibility in IE 11. You could [open an issue](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues) on Tabulator GitHub to ask for fixing it.

For now, as a workaround, we could re-bind the "tab" keyboard shortcut with `navNext` to avoid the issue on IE 11. You could refer to the docs about [Key Bindings](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/keybindings). The sample code to re-bind "tab" is like below:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ...
    keybindings: {
        "navNext": "tab", 
    },
});
```

Comment: This does fix the rendering issue when tabbing out of the select editor but another issue pops up. If I change any editable values I am tabbed out of the table and lose the 'navNext' flow to the next cell. I'll submit an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue and I added an answer in the already closed topic in github repo https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3125#issuecomment-769871958

There is a parameter that it is not declared in the Tabulator variable. Once is added, the information appeared.
That was caused my confusion. Would I suggest to add the full script in order to not miss that 'data: tabledata' parameter?

Then the example code will be something like this (approx) :

```
<Script> 
    //Create Date Editor
    var dateEditor = function(cell, onRendered, success, cancel){
        //cell - the cell component for the editable cell
        //onRendered - function to call when the editor has been rendered
        //success - function to call to pass the successfuly updated value to Tabulator
        //cancel - function to call to abort the edit and return to a normal cell
    
        //create and style input
        var cellValue = moment(cell.getValue(), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        input = document.createElement("input");
    
        input.setAttribute("type", "date");
    
        input.style.padding = "4px";
        input.style.width = "100%";
        input.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    
        input.value = cellValue;
    
        onRendered(function(){
            input.focus();
            input.style.height = "100%";
        });
    
        function onChange(){
            if(input.value != cellValue){
                success(moment(input.value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
            }else{
                cancel();
            }
        }
    
        //submit new value on blur or change
        input.addEventListener("blur", onChange);
    
        //submit new value on enter
        input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                onChange();
            }
    
            if(e.keyCode == 27){
                cancel();
            }
        });
    
        return input;
    };
    
    //define some sample data
    var tabledata = [
        {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:"",car:true},
        {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982",car:true},
        {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982",car:true},
        {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980",car:true},
        {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999",car:true},
    ];
    
    //Build Tabulator
    var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height:311,
        data: tabledata,
        columns:[
            {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150, editor:"input"},
            //{title:"Location", field:"location", width:130, editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{allowEmpty:true, showListOnEmpty:true, values:true}},
            {title:"Age", field:"age", sorter:"number", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress", width:140, editor:true},
            //{title:"Gender", field:"gender", editor:"select", editorParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female", "unknown":"Unknown"}}},
            //{title:"Rating", field:"rating",  formatter:"star", hozAlign:"center", width:100, editor:true},
            {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", hozAlign:"center", sorter:"date", width:140, editor:dateEditor},
            {title:"Driver", field:"car", hozAlign:"center", editor:true, formatter:"tickCross"}//,
    
        ]//,
    });

</Script>
```